# Finding city polygon for Brisbane, Australia using OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, polygon, data, australia

I can't seem to find a polygon for the city of Brisbane, Australia. I can only find a Point. Is there another name i should be searching for? ie. city, municipality.

I've searched for "Brisbane, Australia", "Brisbane City, Australia", "Brisbane Municipality, Australia", "Brisbane Region, Australia"... I'm looking for a polygon that circles the city of Brisbane. Similar to what comes up when you search for "Greater Melbourne, Australia" (place_id=156135873) or "Sydney, Australia" (place_id=156208530)‌​. It needs to come from OpenStreetMap.

Comment: Can you give more information about what you've searched for and why the results aren't good enough.  Are you just after OpenStreetMap data for [Brisbane](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Brisbane), or will any polygon data for Brisbane do.

Comment: I've searched for "Brisbane, Australia", "Brisbane City, Australia", "Brisbane Municipality, Australia", "Brisbane Region, Australia"... I'm looking for a polygon that circles the city of Brisbane. Similar to what comes up when you search for "Greater Melbourne, Australia" (place_id=156135873) or "Sydney, Australia" (place_id=156208530). It needs to come from OpenStreetMaps...

Comment: There is kml/xml file here http://results.ecq.qld.gov.au/profiles/xml/Brisbane_City_Council.xml?tmp=0.08274824403775394 includes Moreton Island source http://results.ecq.qld.gov.au/interactive_maps/local-government-map.html?council=Brisbane%20City%20Council save it and will open in Google Earth (or QGIS)

Comment: That's perfect. However i've setup the nominatim server and its not on there. That is where i need to get it from...

Comment: Brisbane City Council advocates open data so I think you would be better asking this on the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Currently there is no administrative boundary polygon for Brisbane in OSM.

Comment: You can extract the boundary from https://data.qld.gov.au/dataset/local-government-area-boundaries-queensland. It is CC BY 3.0 AU but I am unsure of the nuances (legal) in importing into OSM.

Answer (score 3):

You can look up the administrative borders in OSM at https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/. Just expand the tree view in the left panel. Brisbane seems to be still missing.

You get from OpenStreetMap servers only that what other people have uploaded there.

If noone has drawn a polygon with the extact borders, it will not be in the database.

Keep in mind that only licence-compliant data is allowed to be entered into the OSM database. If the city keeps some kind of copyright or mystery on its border, it can not be inserted.

Comment: Url is outdated, page moved to https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/